# Linking User Profile Page to a model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Django. I have created a model for a simple textbox app as follows:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import model                  
class TODO(models.Model):                     
    task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Also, I have created a user login portal. Now I want to activate the model and redirect the user to that page when he logs in.

Comment: What do you mean by &quot;activate  the model&quot;? You should also show what are your views or urls, which are how you accomplish what you want.

Comment: Mind the case of your class python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names Todo instead of TODO.

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation would be like this -

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models

class TODO(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.task
```

***urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from demo import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^todo/$', views.TaskView, name='list-todo'),
]
```

***views.py***

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from demo import models


@login_required
def TaskView(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        todos = models.TODO.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'todo.html', {'todos' : todos})
```

***todo.html***
`Keep the file under a folder named 'templates' under project root`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tasks</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for task in todos %}
    <li>{{ task }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

***settings.py***

1. `Add 'templates'in DIR under TEMPLATES settings -`

   'DIRS': ['templates'],
2. `Add *__'app-name'__* under **INSTALLED_APPS**`

***Perform migrations***

```
./manage.py makemigrations 'app-name'  
./manage.py migrate
```

***Run the APP***
`./manage.py runserver`

For more info checkout the docs page. Happy Coding ;)